# PHP reading next line in text file while using lazy loading?

Tags: php, text-files, splfileobject

I have a text file that I want to read line by line. For each line I also need the value from the next line, so I need something to read the next line while in the current line.

I have read through many answers here that I can do this with a `foreach` loop, but it requires reading the whole file in ahead. I am looking for something to only read as needed.

Here is what I got so far with SplFileObject.

```
$file = new \SplFileObject($textFile);
$lastNumber = 500;

while (!$file->eof()) {
    $currentLine = $file->fgets();

    $currentNumber = intval($currentLine);
    $file->next();

        if ($file->eof()) {
            $nextNumber = intval($lastNumber);
        } else {
            $nextNumber = intval($file->fgets()) - 1;
        }

        echo $currentNumber . ', ' . $nextNumber . '<br>';

}
```

Suppose I have a text that have lines like this

```
0
100
200
300
400
```

I want them to print out like this

```
0, 99
100, 199
200, 299
300, 399
400, 500
```

But my code was skipping every other line

```
0, 99
200, 299
400, 500
```

My guess is that my while loop and the `$file->next()` each moves the line by 1 every loop, that's why the skip. But without the `next()` call, I don't know how to get the value of the next line. How do I fix this?

Comment: You could create a simple stack. Put two lines on it the first run before doing a loop. Then start the loop, you have current and next available. In the loop itself pull current from stack, read next line and push to stack.

Answer (score -1):

Use this PHP Code Solution.

```php
  $textFile = 'text.txt';

  $file = new SplFileObject($textFile);
  $lastNumber = 500;

  foreach ($file as $lineNumber => $line) {
    $currentNumber = intval($file->current());

    if ($lineNumber === 0) {
      $previousNumber = $currentNumber;
      continue;
    } else {
      $nextNumber = $currentNumber - 1;
      echo $previousNumber . ', ' . $nextNumber . '<br>';

      $previousNumber = $currentNumber;

      if ($file->eof()) {
        $nextNumber = intval($lastNumber);
        echo $currentNumber . ', ' . $nextNumber . '<br>';
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Will this do lazy loading?

Comment: What do mean by lazy loading? This is PHP not JAVASCRIPT. Please explain the exact functionality you want to achieve.